# What's the propper use of && operator in a do while loop?

Tags: c, cs50

I could not understand why the program defines Heigth only for greater values then 9, I would be very pleased if someone can show me my mistake, thank you for your time.

```
#include <cs50.h>
include <stdio.h>

int Heigth;

int main(void) { 
    do { 
        Heigth = get_int("A level value please ? ");    
    } while (9 > Heigth && Heigth > 0); 

    printf("Heigth is %d", Heigth);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ ./mario
A level value please ? 5
A level value please ? 7
A level value please ? 98
Heigth is 98$ ^C
```

Comment: It's `9>Heigth`, which is equivalent to `Heigth < 9`, so that means only values between 0 and 9 are accepted as input. Once `Height` is not in that range, the loop is stopped

Comment: What mistake?  What are you trying to do that the code isn't doing?  If you want it to accept values between 0 and 9 (inclusive), then you need to reverse the sense of the test - `while( Heigth > 9 || Heigth < 0 );`.

Comment: Normally one thinks "if height between 0 and 9", or `0< height <= 9`, which translates in C to:   `if (0<height && height<=9)`

Comment: Looks like you have it backwards. Either switch directions of the `<` and `>` or just change the while to `(!9 > Heigth && !Heigth > 0);`

Comment: @Aroic that's not gonna do what you think it will..

Comment: Don't shout please. Don't use CAPS LOCK

Comment: Ugh. I hate this syntax -- it makes the purpose of the code so unclear. But Bjarne Stroustrup uses it, so I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code fragment:

```
do {
    something();
} while (condition1 && condition2);
```

means to repeat `something()` if both `condition1` and `condition2` are true. In your case, `get_int()` will be called repeatedly if `Height` is between 9 and 0. That is, both `9 > Height` and `Height > 0` are true.

If you actually meant to repeat calling `get_int` if `Height` was greater than 8 or less than 1, then you have to write the condition to say that. But, then you would not use `&&`. You would write `8 < Height || Height < 1` instead.

In boolean logic, it is true that ¬(A ∧ B) ≡ (¬A ∨ ¬B), so you could get the equivalent behavior by negating your original expression.

```
do {
    something();
} while (!(condition1 && condition2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `&&` in any conditioned cycle is to join conditions.

In your program, you specify that while  both `9 > Heigth` and  `Heigth > 0` conditions are met, the cycle will repeat itself.

`9 > Heigth` is not really the usual format, normally the variable comes before the literal so it would be preferable to have `Heigh < 9`.

So to translate it to text this means that the cycle will repeat itself while the inputed number is less than `9` and also more than `0`, so values that range from 2 to 8, including.

If a number that doesn't meet the condition is inputed the cycle will end and the program will continue to the next instruction, in this case it will exit.

Comment: There is no general convention to place an identifier before a literal in a comparison. It is not abnormal to put the constant first. (In fact, placing the literal first when comparing for equality may be preferred since `a == 9` may accidentally become `a = 9` with a typo, which the compiler accepts, but, with the same typo, `9 = a` will not be accepted by the compiler.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I didn't refer the convention, only that it's not common seeing `9 > a`, never really though of it as a failsafe, that's a good idea, however for `a = 9` inside a condition a `-Wall` flag will render a `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]` (gcc 9.2.0)